# react-native-beacons-manager can't detect any beacons iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, ibeacon

I have followed the examples on how to use the react-native-beacons-manager here: https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager/blob/master/examples/samples/monitoringAndRanging.ios.md
but I can't detect any beacons in the area, even though I have a beacon device with me. and I'm quite confused on the hard-coded region here:

```
const region = {
       identifier: 'Estimotes',
       uuid: 'B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D'
   };
```

What are these identifier and UUID? is it safe to use it or should I get it somewhere for me to start detecting beacons? here is my relevant code I have omitted some irrelevant code:

```
import Beacons from 'react-native-beacons-manager';

class HomeTab extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 }
  );
   this.state = {
     region: {
       latitude: LATITUDE,
       longitude: LONGITUDE,
       latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
       longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
     }
   };
 }

componentWillMount(){

     Beacons.requestAlwaysAuthorization();

     const region = {
       identifier: 'Estimotes',
       uuid: 'B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D'
   };


   Beacons.startMonitoringForRegion(region) // or like  < v1.0.7: .startRangingBeaconsInRegion(identifier, uuid)
   .then(() => console.log('Beacons monitoring started succesfully'))
   .catch(error => console.log(`Beacons monitoring not started, error: ${error}`));
   // Range for beacons inside the region
   Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region) // or like  < v1.0.7: .startRangingBeaconsInRegion(identifier, uuid)
   .then(() => console.log('Beacons ranging started succesfully'))
   .catch(error => console.log(`Beacons ranging not started, error: ${error}`));
   // update location to ba able to monitor:
   Beacons.startUpdatingLocation();
 }

componentDidMount(){
 this.beaconsDidRangeEvent = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
       'beaconsDidRange',
       (data) => {
         console.log('beaconsDidRange data: ', data);

       }
     );

  this.beaconsDidRangeEvent = Beacons.BeaconsEventEmitter.addListener(
    'beaconsDidRange',
    (data) => {
      console.log('beaconsDidRange data: ', data);

    }
  );

     // monitoring events
     this.regionDidEnterEvent = Beacons.BeaconsEventEmitter.addListener(
       'regionDidEnter',
       (data) => {
         console.log('monitoring - regionDidEnter data: ', data);

       }
     );

}
}
```

Comment: The uuid you specify in the region must match the uuid your beacon is advertising.

Comment: @Paulw11 hmm, can you elaborate further? does my current region is wrong? what is that Estimotes? is that a country?

Comment: Estimote is a brand of beacon.  Your beacons will be configured with a specific UUID.  You need to know what UUID your beacons have (or set it to something known) and then specify that UUID in your region specification. The identifier doesn't matter. It can be anything

Comment: @Paulw11 hmm, please tell me if my understanding is correct, my goal in my app is to detect beacons in the area, to be able to achieve that I need to have a UUID of a beacon(I can't understand this part because, what I just want is to detect beacons why do I need to have a UUID of a beacon in my app)?

so you are telling me to put the UUID of my sample beacon in my app to be
 able to detect it?

Comment: Yes.  Beacons have a UUID, a major number and a minor number.  You must know at least the UUID you are looking for.  You cannot scan for "any beacon".  Typically all of the beacons for a organisation or at a location would be configured with the same UUID and different major/minors to let you determine where the user is.

Comment: I see! I got it now. I must know the UUID of the beacons I want to detect. It's working now. Thank you very much for the enlightenment. Wish I could upvote your comment.